# undefined value javascript

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm trying to run a javascript function with values ​​but gets the answer val is undefined.

I want to append this value

**Function run**

```
myufunc("test msg");
```

**code**

```
function myufunc(val){
    var script   = document.createElement("script");
    script.type  = "text/javascript";
    script.text  = 'alert(val);';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### The problem

The problem is that your created script-tag will contain `alert(val)`, but `val` hasn't been initialized; it does exists inside your function - but the newly created script-element have no idea what `val` you are referring to.

You probably want the element to end up containing `alert("test msg");`:

```
function f(val){
  var script   = document.createElement("script");
  script.type  = "text/javascript";
  script.text  = 'alert("' + val + '");';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

f ("test msg"); // will create a <script> containing `alert("test msg");`
```

<sup>**Note**: since we are manually wrapping the contents of `val` with double-quotes, be careful so that the passed in value itself doesn't contain a *double-quote* `"`; this will break the "*generated*" code.</sup>

Comment: @BojanaCubranovic Dude, you need to concatenate val into the script string you're inserting to the document. NOT `script.text='alert(val);';` but `script.text='alert("' + val + '");';`

Answer (score 1):

First, "int" is a reserved word in Javascript-

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Second, you are using "val" as if it were a string, not a variable.

```
init("test msg");

function init(val){

var script   = document.createElement("script");
script.type  = "text/javascript";
script.text  = 'alert('+val+');';
document.body.appendChild(script);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

int is a reserved word in JavaScript, so definitely don't use it. That's most likely the reason your code isn't working properly.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `val` is only available in the `myufunc` scope, and when your script is appended, it is executed in the global scope, not your function scope. Thus, `val` is not defined in the global scope.

A solution is to create a global variable and set its value to `val`, then use the global in the alert. Using this way, there is no need to concatenate the variable into the string, and so you don't have the problem of the variable containing quotes and breaking the string.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wCL6r/)**

```
function myufunc(val){
    myValue = val; // create global

    var script   = document.createElement("script");
    script.type  = "text/javascript";
    script.text  = 'alert(myValue);'; // use the global
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

The following will all work:

```
myufunc('test');
myufunc('tes"t');
myufunc("tes't");
```